# Is it Possible to create an array of Condition Statements?

Tags: c#, excel

I am making  conditional statements with excel calls and I was wondering if there was a way to have my program check an array of conditions that it loops through, rather than a bunch of "or" statements.  My code is as follows:

```
while(
    activesheet.Range["A" + n].Text != "sting 1" 
    || activesheet.Range["A" + n].Text != "string 2"
    || activesheet.Range["A" + n].Text != "string 3"...)
{
    n++;
}
```

Is it possible to have an array of conditions that each row of my excel file can be forced to go through?  I can't seem to figure it out and have not found any answers or examples yet.  I think I can use a 'foreach' call but I am not sure how to implement it for my purpose.  Thanks.

Comment: Side note: Shouldn't you be using `||` instead of `|`?

Comment: You really should use `||` instead of `|` so the expression will short circuit on the first `true` and stop evaluating the rest.

Comment: My mistake, that was me posting without thinking.. thanks for the tips though!

Comment: your condition is always true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reverse the logic and use `Contains`:

```
var strings = new[] {"sting 1", "string 2", "string 3"};
while(!strings.Contains(activesheet.Range["A" + n].Text))
{
}
```

However, if you're using Office Interop I would note that `Range[]` and `Text` are both COM calls, which are slow.  You may see significant improvement by not calling them for each string comparison, and instead comparing against a constant in your while loop:

```
while(true)
{
    var value = activesheet.Range["A" + n].Text; // one COM call instead of multiple
    if (strings.Contains(value)) break;
}
```

Comment: `!strings.Contains`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much! @M.kazemAkhgary thank you for the correction

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Thanks - I missed that it was using `!=`.  In that case the original code should be using `&&` instead of `|`.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Interesting, I did not know they were "slow" implementations of my code.  I will take your advice.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Rinktacular Yes COM calls can be _relatively_ slow.  That said, get something that _works_ first and then focus on making it _better_ (that way you can always go back to working code) if it's NOTICEABLY slow.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Linq to turn your code into data which you can iterate through and test like an array - something like this :

```
List<Func<bool>> stepsList = new List<Func<bool>>
        {
            Condition1,
            Condition2,
            ...
        };

stepsList.TrueForAll(f => f());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var conditions = new List<Func<Range, bool>>();

foreach (Range r in allMyXlsRanges)
{
    while (conditions.TrueForAll(c => c(r)))
    {
        //whatever
    }
}
```

With this setup you only need to initialize your conditions once:

```
 conditions.Add(r => r.Text != "string 1");
 conditions.Add(r => r.Text != "string 2");
 //etc.
```

This is basically the same solution [auburg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763382/auburg) has posted but allowing you to iterate through a collection of ranges which is what I think you are trying to do.